# Can a (modern) React functional component expose a stateful method externally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

Can my React functional component expose externally a method with access to internal state?

```
interface Inner {
  foo: string
}

function Inner(props: Inner) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState<string>(props.foo + "baz")
    
  function doTheThing() {
    console.log(`doin' that ${foo} thing`)
  }

  return <div>{props.foo}</div>
}

function Outer() {
  const inner = <Inner foo="bar" />

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => inner.doTheThing()}>
        Do That Thing
      </button>
      {inner}
    </>
  )
}
```

This of course gives me an error: `TypeError: inner.doTheThing is not a function`.

I can use a class component to expose a method like this. But is there a way (with hooks? with refs?) to make this work with a functional component?

Comment: How exactly would you do that with a class component? Using `new Inner`? Regardless, this is one of those questions where the answer is - you're going about this the wrong way. Lift state up, if that's not an option for some reason then look into refs.

Comment: @BrianThompson With a class component, I think I could do something like: `const inner = <Inner ... />; const button = <button onClick={inner.doTheThing()} .../>`, right? (I have not tried it.) But you're right: I realize this is perhaps a React antipattern, or at least not standard practice. In my actual use case, I'm wrapping an off-the-shelf component that does the `doTheThing` that I need; without writing `doTheThing` myself, which is what I'm trying to avoid here, I'm not sure how to solve it without exposing a method like this.

Comment: No that wouldn't work with a class component either. Once you've added the JSX syntax (as you should) you're not working with a class instance, but a React element with a *type* of that class. If you have no access into the component with the function you need, and it's not already exposed somehow, then there is no way to get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a ref, and then store `doTheThing` reference there.

```
import { MutableRefObject, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface Inner {
  foo: string;
  dRef: MutableRefObject<{ doTheThing: () => void } | undefined>;
}

function Inner(props: Inner) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState<string>(props.foo + "baz");

  function doTheThing() {
    console.log(`doin' that ${foo} thing`);
  }

  props.dRef.current = { doTheThing };

  return <div>{props.foo}</div>;
}

export function Outer() {
  const dRef = useRef<{ doTheThing: () => void }>();
  const inner = <Inner foo="bar" dRef={dRef} />;

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => dRef.current?.doTheThing()}>Do That Thing</button>
      {inner}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you show a brief sketch of how that would look where the reference has access to a state variable of `Inner`?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Ah, cool. Part of my issue was trying to pass in a prop called `ref` to `Inner`; looks like you're using `dRef` to avoid clashing with the React keyword.

Comment: If you really want to name it `ref`, then you'd need to use `forwardRef` to properly handle it.